# Is sysconf(_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES) expected to match sysinfo() free memory?

Tags: c, linux, memory, out-of-memory

I'm trying to monitor available memory of the Linux system in my C code to handle near out-of-memory situation and I tried to do

```
long available_mem = sysconf(_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES) * pagesize;
```

but it appears that if I run this same code repeatedly, the value matches free memory reported by `sysinfo()` instead of `MemAvailable` from `/proc/meminfo`. Is this expected? (If I actually try to use even close to `available_mem` worth of memory, the system will be swapping a lot so it seems that it doesn't match the actually available memory.)

Is there a way to get current value of `MemAvailable` (or close realtime approximation) without parsing strings from `/proc/meminfo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that GNU libc documentation lies... According to [the libc documantation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Query-Memory-Parameters.html)

> ```
>     sysconf (_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES)
> ```
>
> The value returned for _SC_AVPHYS_PAGES is the amount of memory the application can use without hindering any other process (given
> that no other process increases its memory usage). The value returned
> for _SC_PHYS_PAGES is more or less a hard limit for the working set.
> If all applications together constantly use more than that amount of
> memory the system is in trouble.

However, [the actual source code of `sysconf()`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/posix/sysconf.c.html#636) says

```
636     case _SC_AVPHYS_PAGES:
637       return __get_avphys_pages ();
```

and the [definition of `__get_avphys_pages()`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/getsysstats.c.html#__get_avphys_pages) reads

```
328  long int
329  __get_avphys_pages (void)
330  {
331    struct sysinfo info;
332 
333    __sysinfo (&info);
334    return sysinfo_mempages (info.freeram, info.mem_unit);
335  }
```

So obviously the returned value is not "the amount of memory the application can use without hindering any other process" which would match `MemAvailable` from `/proc/meminfo` but amount of `.freeram` from kernel system call `sysinfo()`.

So the end result is not expected according to the documentation, but it's expected according to the actual implementation.